Random ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR errors on certain browsers
A number of users of my websites are reporting seeing error messages like "The connection to this website is not secure - SSL_ERR_PROTOCOL_ERROR" randomly with different frequency. The problem occurs randomly, but is limited to certain browsers. It affects all sites served from that server.
It only affects MS Edge and Chrome (Mac and Windows), but never Firefox (Mac, v127) or Safari (any version). It happens randomly - sometimes once for every 10 or 20 requests (GET and POST), sometimes 5 times in a row.
I was able to get a pcap for two of the failed connections, and the cause appears to be a TLSv1.2 "illegal parameter" alert (47, fatal) issued by the client.
The server running all these sites is Apache v2.4 on macOS, using Let's Encrypt certificates.
My understanding is that while the alert does not specify which parameter is "illegal", it can be related to the cipher suite negotiation. In my pcap, the Client Hello offers a number of cipher suites, among them TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030); the Server Hello then contains just that one cipher suite (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384). To my limited TLS knowledge, that looks okay...?
What can be the reason for this random but very annoying problem? And why are Firefox and Chrome not affected?  (I'll be happy to update this question with more information about the server config if necessary. Just drop a comment what you need to know.)
Update (2024-06-28): Here is a screenshot of the cert for one of these sites, from when the problem does not occur. Of course there is not certificate to display when the connections fails.

The connection is always TLSv1.2. The S/N of the cert transmitted by the server when the problem occurs (as seen in the packet capture) is the correct one, so it's not the wrong cert.
One thing I've noticed is that in the successful case, the server sends a "change cipher spec" message together with the Server Hello. In the failure case, this does not occur.

What security products do you have installed on your system and do you have any features that might have installed invalid certificates in order to scan encrypted HTTP traffic?

@Ramhound None – and all certificates on that machine have been created by certbot (Let's Encrypt.)

So you have no third-party installed? When this error occurs is the correct TLS being offered? Provide a screenshot of the certificate for us.

Nothing that could affect the connection or certificate. The problem appears not to be with the certificate, but rather with the TLS negotiation (see my update of the question.)
